# Rango de fecha de expiracion de cuenta LDAP

Tags: visual-studio, vb.net, activedirectory

Lo que necesito es poder enviar al AD una fecha inicial y una fecha final para que una determinada cuenta expire solo en ese rango de fechas, algo así :

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

He encontrado instrucciones para reactivar una cuenta (poniendo 0) o expirarla dándole una fecha, pero no encuentro manejar el rango de fechas que les comento:

```
Public Sub Expirar(CuentaAD As String, Fexpira? As Date, Usuario As String, Clave As String)
    Dim ctx As New DirectoryEntry("LDAP://" & CuentaAD, Usuario, Clave)

    If Fexpira Is Nothing Then
        ctx.InvokeSet("accountExpires", 0)
    Else
        ctx.InvokeSet("AccountExpirationDate", Fexpira)
    End If
    ctx.CommitChanges()
    ctx.Close()
End Sub
```